# How can I connect my android phone to wired DSL(pppoe) network which is running on my pc (Ubuntu - 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, android, pppoe, dsl

I am using a wired DSL pppoe network on my laptop using following commands -

1) run sudo pppoeconf
   2) Enter root password
   3) Answered all questions with answer - "Yes"
   4) finally run pon dsl-provider

and I'm able to connect to internet. But firstly, my network indicator panel disappeared.

Secondly, I'm not be able to connect any of my mobile devices to internet by making my pc as hotspot.

I have searched many solutions which I felt not enough descriptive. Please suggest me how can I fix it.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I've tried this myself and the issue is likely your phone from my experience. *Most* android phones can passthrough network and internet information over RNDIS via USB, *but* cannot receive network passthrough on the other end. Some devices I'm sure are exceptions but I can't confirm.